# Switching tabs in react destroys the tab content . Is there any way the persist the content?

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

I'm working on an react web app in which I created tabs dynamically using  kendo .

The problem is that when I click on a tab, fill it's content, then click on another tab, and then come back to that tab, its data (value entered in text box) disappears because the tab is reloaded again.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are making a ajax call each time a tab is selected and/or reselected. There is no built in persistence that I know of. I would look for an event that can be intercepted with the ability to cancel the ajax call to the server based on your custom tab state.

Comment: each tab has a react component.  No ajax call

Comment: Post some of your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TabStrip` component `keepTabsMounted` prop. The default behavior is to unmount each tab when it isn't currently visible. If you set `keepTabsMounted` to true, all the tabs will stay mounted after they are unselected.

[See the Kendo docs here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/layout/api/TabStripProps/#toc-keeptabsmounted)

Another solution would be to keep the state of the tabs in the parent component so that the state would not be lost when the tab is unmounted.